# Create HoG feature matrix, array

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, feature-extraction

I want to use HoG to extract features from a set if (16) images. I have done for one image, and it returned a good result. Now I want to do for all other images, and store the features.
.
Please how do I create a matrix/array to store the features for classification.
All my images are in a single folder...
Here is my code so far, pls help:

```
%% Load Images
imgFolder =   fullfile('C:\Users\Engineering\Desktop\Finn\NEW');
 imgSet = imageSet(imgFolder);

 %% Display Montage of First Note
 figure;
 montage(imgSet(1).ImageLocation);
 title('Images of Single Note');

 %%  Display Query Image and Database Side-Side
 galleryImage = read(imgSet,1);
 figure;
 for i=1:size(imgSet,2)
imageList = imgSet(i).ImageLocation;
 end

         subplot(1,2,1);imshow(galleryImage);
 subplot(1,2,2);montage(imageList);
 diff = zeros(1,9);

 %% Split Database into Training & Test Sets
 [training,test] = partition(imgSet,[0.8 0.2]);

 %% Extract and display Histogram of Oriented Gradient Features for single Note 
 [hogFeature, visualization]= ...
     extractHOGFeatures(read(training,1));
 figure;
  subplot(2,1,1);imshow(read(training,1));title('Input Note');
 subplot(2,1,2);plot(visualization);title('HoG Feature');

 %% Extract HOG Features for training set

 I need help in this section, please. Thank you
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly. You wish to have a multidimensional array with Hog Features of all the images. If that is the case, here is a simple solution

```
 accum = [];
 for i = 1:training.Count
     [hogFeature, visualization]= ...
         extractHOGFeatures(read(training,i));
     accum = [accum;hogFeature];
 end
```

Now, each row of `accum` matrix is a set of Hog Features for the corresponding image. Hog Features of n-th image can be accessed by `features = accum(n,:);`.

Comment: Thank you Harnatin. I will try the codes and come back.

Comment: Okay. But one more line is missing: I need to use it for classifier=fitcecoc(features, label); to get the label part, I tried using: label=training(i).Description; but it returned error... Index exceeds matrix dimension. How do I resolve this. Thank you

Comment: please am lost again. To do classifier. I need those two args: fitcecoc(x,y). X=features. What is y?

Comment: y is the label associated with the particular training example.